# modify form to only display current user information, aspnet

Tags: asp.net

the current page code below lists profile information of all users within with my site. i'd like to modify it so that it only displays information about the current user logged in.  Thanks.

----------aspx page----------
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>

```
MembershipUserCollection users;

public void Page_Load()
{
  users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    // Bind users to ListBox.
    UsersListBox.DataSource = users;
    UsersListBox.DataBind();
  }


  // If a user is selected, show the properties for the selected user.

  if (UsersListBox.SelectedItem != null)
  {
    MembershipUser u = users[UsersListBox.SelectedItem.Value];

    EmailLabel.Text = u.Email;
    IsOnlineLabel.Text = u.IsOnline.ToString();
    LastLoginDateLabel.Text = u.LastLoginDate.ToString();
    CreationDateLabel.Text = u.CreationDate.ToString();
    LastActivityDateLabel.Text = u.LastActivityDate.ToString();
  }
}

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Sample: View User Information</title>
</head>
<body>

<form runat="server" id="PageForm">

  <h3>View User Information</h3>

  <table border="0" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <asp:ListBox id="UsersListBox" DataTextField="Username" 
                     Rows="8" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
           <td>E-mail:</td>
           <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="EmailLabel" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Is Online?:</td>
           <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="IsOnlineLabel" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>LastLoginDate:</td>
           <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="LastLoginDateLabel" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>CreationDate:</td>
           <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="CreationDateLabel" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>LastActivityDate:</td>
           <td><asp:Label runat="server" id="LastActivityDateLabel" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Membership.GetUser()` to get the currently logged user (if any)